# Channeling constraints in OR TOOLS

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

When we use the channeling constraints, example taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling):

```py
# Implement b == (x >= 5).
model.Add(x >= 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
model.Add(x < 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())

# Create our two half-reified constraints.
# First, b implies (y == 10 - x).
model.Add(y == 10 - x).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
# Second, not(b) implies y == 0.
model.Add(y == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
```

Do we **have to** specify the `boolean_var.Not()` for all the implication? Can we just describe the above program without `.Not()` specification of the boolean? I mean, if I only care about `x >= 5`, so do I still have to specify `x < 5` inequality and out the `boolean_var.Not()` for it? Is this compulsory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify it, you can have x == 5 and b == false.

Which will be problematic for the state of y.